# Paramiko logging config

Tags: logging, paramiko

I see the suggestion to incorporate the paramiko logging in a python class as follows:

logging.getLogger("paramiko").setLevel(logging.WARNING)

Does this mean in my logger, I have to add a logger with name "paramiko" in my existing list, which looks like this:

```
'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handlers': ['log_file', 'sentry'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['log_file', 'sentry'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'raven': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console', 'log_file'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'sentry.errors': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console', 'log_file'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
    },
}
```

I am new to python and paramiko. I would like to know if there are unit tests in python to see which logger is being referenced such as root or specifically named one?

Answer (score 0):

just add

```
paramiko.util.get_logger().setLevel(logging.WARNING) on your application
```

Or if by not specifying it will have the same level as your custom logger